How I can use the AWS CLI to see whether an S3 bucket has versioning activated?
How I can use the AWS CLI (aws s3) to see whether an S3 bucket has versioning activated?

s3api is the CLI command you want:
aws s3api get-bucket-versioning --bucket BUCKET_NAME

Example of output for a bucket where bucket versioning is enabled:
{
    "Status": "Enabled"
}

